# export to pdf in radcalendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-scheduler

i can see Export to PDF Editor, Export to PDF Grid, Pdf Export Scheduler but cannot see export to pdf for radcalendar.i need to export a radcalendar to pdf because it has events shown in different colored dates.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below demo, PDF export in Scheduler is available in new telerik DLL. So, Please update your DLL.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/pdfexport/defaultcs.aspx